# Maven build .war with old files

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a project, it uses maven and work's fine. But sometime ago I decide to change my JDK from 1.6007 to 1.6032 version. And presumably after changing JDK, my Maven build `.war` with old `.class` files. Even after `cleaning` project I get files dated by 24.05(date when I change JDK), but I compiled them TODAY. 
NOTE: all  problems are related with .war file (may be with maven-war-plugin, but I don't change properties of plugin since it work fine), because I also use Jetty as local web-server for testing, and in Jetty all works fine.
Thanks,

**EDIT:** I noticed that when I run `package` goal, maven always use different JDK versions (I see it in Eclipse console)

Comment: It is one thing to update JDK on your system and another for maven to know this.  Possibly your JAVA_HOME still points to the older JDK?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the compiler version for maven-compiler-plugin

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <executable><!-- path-to-javac --></executable>
          <compilerVersion>1.6032</compilerVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```